# How can I word wrap code block output in ChatGPT?

Tags: chatgpt

I often like to have ChatGPT output things in a code block, not because I'm working on code, but just to keep specific output visually separated.  The trouble is, it's never word wrapped and so reading anything where the lines are wider than about 70 characters, becomes tedious.

I keep asking it to word wrap to 70 characters, and it keeps saying it will do so, but then doesn't do it.

Is there a way to force code block output from ChatGPT, to 70 characters in width?

Answer (score 5):

I asked chatGPT how to do it and it told me!

> Is it possible for you to output text in a code block, that is wrapped
> to be only 70 characters wide?  If so, how would I ask you to do that?

```
Yes, it's possible for me to output text in a code block that is wrapped to be 
only 70 characters wide. You can ask me to do that by using the following syntax:

wrap 70
[Your text goes here]
wrap

Replace [Your text goes here] with the text you want me to output, and I will wrap 
it to be 70 characters wide inside a code block.
```

Comment: Ah, but does it actually work or was it simply saying something that you would think looks like a good answer?

Comment: It works, most of the time.  But it does in time seem to lose track of it, as it does with so many things.  But it works at first.  I'm working on getting it to stick.

Comment: Related [Should GPT / ChatGPT generated answers be banned?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4877/88163). TL;DR: This answer should be considered an exception and not to be used as proof that generated text content answers are generally allowed in [webapps.se].

Comment: \**[ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT)* (not *[chatGPT](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170232/edit)*)

Comment: It would probably only do this *after* writing the output telling you how to make it do this.